# Saving user input in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var userSites = newArray();
    var max_fields = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed 
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 5; //initial text box count
    $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) {
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name ="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

I have this code, because I want to have a lot of user inputs. However, once the user inputs this stuff, how do I save this into an array? Is that possible? I want to save it into an array that I can access from a java applet, is that possible as well?

Comment: So what you're really asking is how to send data to the server ?

Comment: Is the Java running on the client or the server?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking to send data to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, now that the user has input this stuff, how do I save this into an array? Is that possible? I want to save it into an array that I can access from a java applet?

When the form is submitted, the event handler, `collectData` gathers the text in each `<input>` and uses the [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to populate an array. This array is then stored in a hidden `<input>` and that data is then extracted by the form which then posts to the server.

I don't know much about Java applets but I got you this far. I suggest you ask about Java in a new question. Your tags are of a JavaScript/jQuery nature.

My demo actually functions with a test server so once submitted, the server will respond with the data that was posted to it.

This works: http://plnkr.co/edit/seD0L3oI7dTnXQrrFZPl?p=preview

## Added Code

```
  form.addEventListener('submit', collectData, false);

  function collectData(e) {
    var userSites = [];
    var cache = document.getElementById('cache');
    var z = 0;
    while (z < max_fields) {
      z++;
      var data = inputs[z].val();
      userSites.push(data);
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    cache.value = userSites;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array object in your one of you script tags :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
   var myArr=new Array();
</script>
```

Now add onchange to your inputs also update myArr :

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name ="myText'+x.toString()+'" onchange="myArr.push(this.value);document.getElementById('myArrInput').value=JSON.stringify(myArr);" /><a href="#" class="remove_field" onclick="myArr['+x.toString()+'].value=null;document.getElementById('myArrInput').value=JSON.stringify(myArr);" >Remove</a></div>');
```

Add this hiddenField to your page to send myArr to you applet as JSON string:

```
<input id="myArrInput" type="hidden" name="myArray" value="" />
```

In server you have to convert myArray Json string to object.